# How can I roll my own auto-scaling on heroku?

Tags: heroku, autoscaling

Heroku doesn't offer auto-scaling for anything under the "performance tier" dynos ($250/mo).

Hirefire used to be a gem that you could configure to autoscale dynos, but they realized that their solution could make money so now it's a paid service.

What options are there (including rolling my own) for smaller apps to have intelligent scaling of dynos at no extra cost?

Answer (score 4):

The cheapest solution in term of money, but at the cost of time would be to use Heroku's Platform API. The [formation endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation) will let you scale up and down the number of dynos.

Then, you "just" need to gather information on how many dynos you need. For example, with the [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics) feature and a [log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains), you could listen for the cpu and memory usage on your dynos and scale up/down based on that.