# Get Heroku dyno metrics via API

Tags: heroku-api

I am trying to write a Heroku auto scaling script. I want to base the auto scaling on the memory usage, dyno load and response time metrics that are available on the dashboard.

However I am not able to find an API endpoint in their documentation that will give me metrics data.

The closest thing that I was able to find is a [log-runtime-metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), a Heroku Labs module, that writes the CPU and memory usage in the syslog every 20 seconds.

I then need to fetch and parse the log in order to get some meaningful data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179033/855475).

Is there an API for this? Or a better way of doing it?

Comment: Interested in this as well